# Why is $\frac{d(c*t)}{dt} = c + c'*t$?

Tags: integration

I have found in one of my courses the following equality however I don't understand why is it equal.

$$\frac{d(c*t)}{dt} = c + c'*t$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule): $c$ here is (implicitly) assumed to be a function of $t$, so that you apply the rule
$$
(uv)^\prime = u^\prime v + u v^\prime
$$
noticing that $\frac{d}{dt} t = 1$.

Comment: Even if $c$ is not a function of $t$, the equation is right. Of course, in that case, $c^\prime=\frac{d}{dt}c = 0$

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I assume in that context, it was a non-zero derivative (otherwise, the formula seems overkill).